# Menu not working in my Fragment using Actionbar

Tags: android, menu

In my fragment i am using two menu items,one for setting and another one for gridview.When i am clicking any one of menu item which is not triggered.And put log on Onoptionitemselected but not entered inside this please any one help me thanks...

```
 @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {


            menu.clear();
            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settingmenu, menu);
            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menugridcalendar, menu);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);


        }


    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu_setting:
                Log.i(TAG,"InsdieGridmenu");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.gridmenuid:
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (activity instanceof ListItemClickListener) {
                    ((ListItemClickListener)activity).OpenGridView();
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;


        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that in your `onCreate()` you set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

Comment: Are you using actionbarsherlock?

Comment: If you are not using actionbarsherlock library, try put the line `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` inside `onCreate()` instead of `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hai i found answer to my question.if you are using menus in action bar the following onCreateOptionsMenu is defined in your fragment based upon your need.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settingmenu, menu);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menulistcalendar, menu);

    }
```

And your OptionItemSelected actions are must written in Main Actionbar activity.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_setting:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.gridmenuid:
        this.OpenGridView();
    }
    return true;
}
```